# How do I convert a long long into a string?

Tags: c, string, long-long, asprintf

I am creating a program that takes a numerical input from the user as a long long, and then there is some maths involved with individual digits. I think the best way to do this is to convert the long long to a string and then iterate over the various parts.

I have tried using `atoi` but that did not work, and now i am playing with `sprintf` as follows...

```
if (count == 13 || count == 15 || count == 16)
    {
        char str_number[count];
        // Converting long card_number to a string (array of chars)
        sprintf(str_number, "%lld", card_number);
        printf("card number is: %s\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

This does not work either.

Can anyone set me on the right track please?

Comment: `printf("card number is: %s\n");` you mean `printf("card number is: %s\n", str_number);` else the behavior is undefined because the argument for `%s`is missing

Comment: Note also that, if `count` is the number of digits you have, then you will need `count+1` elements in your `str_number` array (space for the null-terminator).

Comment: I do not understand how you can compare *atoi* and *sprintf*,  the first extract (poorly) a number from a string and the second does the reverse operation as you use it. Not *sprintf* does not 'convert' but print/write

Comment: @bruno. Thanks for that, it has compiled now. Now to see if it works (i meant `itoa` :)

Comment: @Adrian Mole. Thanks, always forget about the pesky null char

Comment: There is std::atoll https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi

Comment: This is a well-known CS50 exercise you are working on. For this exercise, it is better to read the card “number” as a string of characters and operate on those, not to read them as a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

> ```
> printf("card number is: %s\n");
> ```

you missed to give *str_number* in argument, the behavior is undefined, do

```
printf("card number is: %s\n", str_number);
```

Note if your `long long` are on 64b a string sized 21 if enough because the longer string is for `-4611686018427387903` needing 20 characters more the final null character.

---

From your remark :

> Whats the best way to convert the long to a string?

there is no standard *lltoa* so *sprintf* family is the right way, note if you are afraid of writing out of the array you can use *snprintf*

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Whats the best way to convert the long to a string?

Comment: @EdCase for me *sprintf* ( or *snprintf* ...) is the right way, and a portable one